# CONVERT TO INT DATABASE YEAR MONTH HOUR MINUTE MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to convert from a column in SQL but I'm having an error. How to convert this properly?

Tried:

```
(CONVERT([int],(((right(datepart(year, [dbo.QI_Data.DateEntered]),(2))*(100000000)
                       +datepart(month, [dbo.QI_Data.DateEntered])*(1000000))
                       +datepart(day, [dbo.QI_Data.DateEntered])*(10000))
                       +datepart(hour, [dbo.QI_Data.DateEntered])*(100))
                       +datepart(minute, [dbo.QI_Data.DateEntered]))) AS DateEnteredToInt
```

I'm getting the column from another table called QI_Data and column DateEntered. I'm creating view

Also I'm getting:

> Arithmetic overflow error expression

Comment: and what does the column format look like?

Comment: `[dbo.QI_Data.DateEntered]` looks to be quoted in the wrong way. Try `dbo.[QI_Data].[DateEntered]` - quote the separate parts, not the whole

Comment: Hi @Hans Kesting, actually correct one. But I'm having Arithmetic overflow error converting experission to data type int When I do Select after creation of views

Comment: For a year of 2000, you would get 200_000_000_000, which is way over the max int value of  2_147_483_647. Try a [bigint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 22*100000000 is more than a MAX_INT, you need to use a BIGINT

```
SELECT (((CONVERT(BIGINT,right(datepart(year, QI_Data.DateEntered),(2)))*(100000000)
                       +CONVERT(BIGINT,datepart(month, QI_Data.DateEntered))*(1000000))
                       +CONVERT(BIGINT,datepart(day, QI_Data.DateEntered))*(10000))
                       +CONVERT(BIGINT,datepart(hour, QI_Data.DateEntered))*(100))
                       +CONVERT(BIGINT,datepart(minute, QI_Data.DateEntered)) AS DateEnteredToInt
FROM (VALUES (GETDATE()))QI_Data(DateEntered)
```

This would do the job to :

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(BIGINT,CONCAT(right(datepart(year, QI_Data.DateEntered),(2)),
        datepart(month, QI_Data.DateEntered),
        datepart(day, QI_Data.DateEntered),
        datepart(hour, QI_Data.DateEntered),
        datepart(minute, QI_Data.DateEntered)
    ))
FROM (VALUES (GETDATE()))QI_Data(DateEntered)
```

Comment: Hi @Delta32000, 

Thanks! That was the correct one. I tried putting BIGINT but only on the first convert. which is wrong. Thanks again!